# django - Howto inject a message in urls.py

Tags: django, django-templates, messaging

I have a third party app that requires a template.

I would like to inject a message in the urls.py so the message
is displayed in the template as I don't have access to the view
of the 3rd party app.

How can this be achieved the DRY way?

**UPDATE**: Trying to give more info regarding this question.

I have django-registration on my site [(outsourcefactor.com)](http://outsourcefactor.com) and any request starting with  "/signup/" redirects to django-registration which is out of my control. I would have wanted to insert a message into django's  message framework so I could print the message in the signup template which is under my control.

I thought the only place that I could insert a message would be in the urls.py, which is just before releasing the control to django-registration, then catch the message in the registration template and display it.

I am using django-messaging for my event-drive messages, and didn't want to pass the message via context processor or ..etc.

I am trying to avoid forking and modifying django-registration. 
Hope this is more clear now.

Comment: Use context processors.<strike/>

Comment: Does the third party app display django messages?

Comment: You should look into using django-registration signals -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10360686/426790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override any of this django-registration [urls](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/registration/backends/default/urls.py) with custom template.

Comment: I have a login.html template which is working great, but needs the login form which django-registration is not providing. I don't want to write a new template. I guess I can add my own backend.

Comment: django-registration doesn't have login views, because django has [django.contrib.auth.views.login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)

Comment: that is exactly my point, I want to send the user to the login page after an activation with a little message saying "oh your account is active go ahead and login". But now I have to send the user to another template that has a link to the login page. No big deal, I can dance around it, but I wanted it to be DRY.