# Django-Registration Activation redirect with django.contrib.messages

Tags: django, message, django-registration, activation

I'm trying to set up my django-registration activation workflow so that when the user hits the activation link it redirects them to the login page with a nice little message using the django messages framework `django.contrib.messages`

Right now, I've managed to send the user back to the homepage using the `success_url` parameter:

```
 url(r'activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
    activate,
    {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend', 'success_url':'/'},
        name='registration_activate',
    ),
```

where `'/'` is the home login view.  I need to set the success message somewhere along the way...perhaps using the `extra_context` field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django-registration is [using signals](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/registration/backends/default/__init__.py#cl-80) to hook on some points. In your case it should be something like:

```
from registration import signals
def register_handler(request, **kwargs):
    messages.success(request, 'Thank you!')
signals.user_registered.connect(register_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

ilvar's response is probably a better way to do it, but I also managed to get it working by wrapping a view around django-registration view.

In `urls.py` I now point to my new view

```
url(r'^accounts/activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
        Custom_Activation_View.as_view(),
        {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'},
        name='registration_activate'),
```

and in my `views.py` file:

```
    class Custom_Activation_View(TemplateView):
        template_name='home.html'

        def get(self, request, backend, success_url=None, extra_context=None, **kwargs):
            messages.success(self.request, 'Activation complete, please login below')

            return activate(self.request, backend, template_name=self.template_name, success_url='/', extra_context=None, **kwargs)
```