# django-registration - redirecting to registration form and displaying message

Tags: django, django-registration, django-1.4

After succesfully registering, the user is redirected to the template 'registration_complete.html'.

Is there any way of changing this behaviour to redirecting the user to the registration page and displaying a message?

I thought of doing something like this in registration_complete.html:

```
{% include 'registration/registration_form.html' with message='Your account has been created. Please check your email for activation instructions' %}
```

But the `form` variable that I use in the template is not available in this view, so the registration form is not shown. Furthermore, I don't know if this is the best way of doing this.

EDIT:

```
url(r'^register/$', 'registration.views.register',
    {
        'backend': 'trabam.apps.accounts.regbackend.Backend',
        'form_class' : UserRegistrationForm,
        'success_url': '/accounts/register'
    },
    name='registration_register'
),
```

How can I set a message in my template after registration is completed?

Comment: Can you please post the url first which takes you to registration page how it is created in your urls.py?? You can specify the `success_url` which will redirect the user to that url on successful registration.

Comment: Yes I just did that. Now, how can I set a message in my template???

Comment: Since Django 1.3, the best solution for displaying a message has been Django's [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/). You add a message in your view, and then add the HTML for the message in the target template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the success_url which will redirect the user to that url on successful registration.

In order to display a message a simple approach would be add a get parameter in the success_url also, but you have to modify the view to get it from request.GET and place in your request context.

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^register/$', 'registration.views.register',
  {
    'backend': 'trabam.apps.accounts.regbackend.Backend',
    'form_class' : UserRegistrationForm,
    'success_url': '/accounts/register/?on_success=true'
  },
    name='registration_register'
 ),
```

in view:

```
on_success = request.GET.get('on_success', None)
context.update({'on_success': on_success})
```

in template:

```
{% if on_success %}
    <p>You are successfully registered</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what I ended up doing was checking the `on_success` variable inside my template through the request context: `request.GET.on_success`

Comment: Another approach would be to use signals -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10360686/426790)

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your urls.py that you are sending the `success_url` as the `register` view itself. You can't do this because it would require you to change `register` view if you want to send a `message` in the context after successful registration.

So, you need to write an extra view. Suppose this file is `accounts/views.py`.

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
def registration_complete(request):
    .....
    form = RegistrationForm()
    .....
    message = "You are successfully registered"
    return render_to_response("registration/registration_form.html", {'form': form, 'message': message})
```

The template `registration/registration_form.html` is the same that will be used by `django-registration`.

`accounts/urls.py`

```
url(r'^registration_complete/', 'accounts.views.registration_complete', name='accounts_registration_complete'),
```

Your urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^registration/register/$', 'registration.register', {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend', 'success_url': 'accounts_registration_complete'}),
    (r'^registration/', include('registration.urls')),)
```

`registration/registration_form.html`

```
{% if message %}
    {{message}}
{% endif %}
.......
{{form.as_p}}
```

So, only after successful registration, your `success_url` will be used which will call the view `registration_complete` defined by you. This view will send `message` in the context which the registration template can use.